# How to use the WSDL generated classes

Tags: c#, soap, amadeus

Hello I have used the WSDL downloaded from Amadeus Developer portal for all services. I do have a type in my program

```
        AmadeusPDT.Fare_DisplayFaresForCityPair ap = new BookingEngine.AmadeusPDT.Fare_DisplayFaresForCityPair();

        // FLIGHT DATES
        List<AmadeusPDT.DateAndTimeDetailsTypeI2> flightDates = new List<AmadeusPDT.DateAndTimeDetailsTypeI2>();
        flightDates.Add(new AmadeusPDT.DateAndTimeDetailsTypeI2 { date = DepartureDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), qualifier = Util.GetQualifierFromFlightType(FlightType) });

        // For multiple flight dates? like that plus or minus date thing?
        ap.dateOfFlight = flightDates.ToArray();

        var results = ap.Dosomething?; // <------
```

I set the flight dates and fare types and what not.. And am not sure how to "call" or "execute" or get results now

Comment: If I did understand what you are meaning, you just have to execute your endpoint; in Amadeus service class you will invoke the method passing your RQ object and then you are going to getting the response for example: 

/*******    
AmadeusWebServicesPTClient _ws = new AmadeusWebServicesPTClient();
Security_Authenticate Rq = new Security_Authenticate
{......};
   
/*Endpoint execution to get the result*/                                                                                                           
var res = _ws.Security_Authenticate(ref _sessionValue, Rq);
/*******

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is something like this.. Now I must learn what is a Session, TransactionFlowLinkType, and ama_SecurityHostedUser

```
        AmadeusPDT.AmadeusWebServicesPTClient c = new AmadeusPDT.AmadeusWebServicesPTClient();
        AmadeusPDT.Session thisSession = new AmadeusPDT.Session();
        AmadeusPDT.TransactionFlowLinkType flowType = new AmadeusPDT.TransactionFlowLinkType();
        AmadeusPDT.AMA_SecurityHostedUser aMA_SecurityHostedUser = new AmadeusPDT.AMA_SecurityHostedUser();

        AmadeusPDT.Fare_DisplayFaresForCityPairReply results = c.Fare_DisplayFaresForCityPair(ref thisSession,ref flowType,aMA_SecurityHostedUser,ap);
```

Comment: Kind of a half-answer isn't it?

Comment: Yes unfortunately there's very little documentation. I will update when I have more. But it answered my own question how to execute an endpoint